# Eclipse Java EE and Tomcat 7: Error 404, requested resource not available

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, tomcat7

Tomcat 7 on Eclipse Java EE is displaying HTTP STATUS 404, and THE REQUESTED RESOURCE IS NOT AVAILABLE.
1) i dont know what i am not doing right? I have read loads of post on the sight and attempted to do what was possible to do, yet nothing has change. In some cases i got back my source code as a downloadable text file.

This is my servlet program below:

```
package dbservlet;

 //all imports here

public class TennisdbaseServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public TennisdbaseServlet() {}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException, IOException {

   Context envContext = null;
   try {

       Context envContext = new InitialContext(); 
       DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/postgres"); 
       Connection con = ds.getConnection();

       Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
       String query = "select * from tennis_teams";
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

       PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
       response.setContentType("text/html");
       out.print("<center><h1>Tennis Teams Info</h1></center>");
       out.print("<html><body><table border=\"1\" cellspacing=10 cellpadding=5>");
       out.print("<th>TEAM NUMBER</th>");
       out.print("<th>PLAYER NO</th>");
       out.print("<th>DIVISION</th>");

       while(rs.next())
       {
           out.print("<tr>");
           out.print("<td>" + rs.getInt("teamno") + "</td>");
           out.print("<td>" + rs.getString("playerno") + "</td>");
           out.print("<td>" + rs.getDouble("division") + "</td>");
           out.print("</tr>");
       }
       out.print("</table></body></html>");
   }  catch (SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (NamingException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
```

}

And following is my /META-INF/Context.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for web application -->

<Context crossContext="true" docBase="TennisdbaseServlet" path="" reloadable="true" >
  <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
   <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
   <Resource name="jdbc/postgres" auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
      driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
      url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tennisDB"
      username="ssssss" 
      password="ssssss" 
      maxActive="20" 
      maxIdle="10"
      maxWait="-1"/>
</Context>
```

And also below is my /Web_INF/web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns   /j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<resource-ref>
<description>postgreSQL DataSource for Tennis Database Application</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/postgres</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<display-name>TennisDatabasePool</display-name>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>TennisdbaseServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>dbservlet.TennisdbaseServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>TennisdbaseServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/TennisdbaseServlet.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The console output is:

```
Nov 28, 2013 1:42:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in   production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java   \jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common  Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;%PATH%;C:\Program Files\System Center Operations Manager 2007\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\System Center Operations Manager 2007\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.30\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.4\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;.
Nov 28, 2013 1:42:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8010"]
Nov 28, 2013 1:42:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 28, 2013 1:42:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 5546 ms
Nov 28, 2013 1:42:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 28, 2013 1:42:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Nov 28, 2013 1:42:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Windows\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\conf\Catalina\localhost\TennisDatabasePool.xml
Nov 28, 2013 1:42:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TennisDatabasePool' did not find a matching property.
Nov 28, 2013 1:42:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8010"]
Nov 28, 2013 1:42:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 28, 2013 1:42:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 10091 ms
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you mention the URL you are trying to hit, which gives you this error?

Comment: This the url that i hit: http://localhost:8010/TennisDatabasePool/WEB-INF/classes/dbservlet/TennisdbaseServlet.java

Comment: You might consider shortening your question to just include what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not provided the URL that you are using, I am guessing that you may be missing the Context Root in your URL. Ideally, you should use a URL similar to this for accessing your servlet:

```
http://<server>:<port>/<context_root>/TennisdbaseServlet.do
```

where `context_root` is usually the name of your application (WAR file). For example, if your WAR file is `MyApplication.war`, then you have to use below URL:

```
http://<server>:<port>/MyApplication/TennisdbaseServlet.do
```

However, you have the option to override this using Context.xml file on Tomcat. For example, below `<Context>` tag in Context.xml would set the context_root to `SomeApp`

```
<Context crossContext="true" docBase="SomeApp" path="" reloadable="true" >
```

Then, to access the same application, you can use URL:

```
http://<server>:<port>/SomeApp/TennisdbaseServlet.do
```

Comment: This is my url: http://localhost:8010/TennisDatabasePool/WEB-INF/classes/dbservlet/TennisdbaseServlet.java

Comment: This is what the screen of 404 error is like:                      http://localhost:8010/TennisDatabasePool/WEB-INF/classes/dbservlet/TennisdbaseServlet.java                                            HTTP Status 404 - 

type Status report

message 

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.47                                                                                                                            I have just edited the root Context advised above, nothing has changed.                                                             Any more help.

Comment: Plz take a look at my TennisdbaseServlet.java and Context.xml codes, Markers are showing the following: 1) No exception of type ServletException can be thrown,..., 2) the method getWriter() is undefined for the type HttpServletResponse, 3) the method setContentType("text/html") is undefined for the type HttpServletResponse; 4) the value of the field TennisdbaseServlet.serialVersionUID is not used; and 5) no grammar constraints (DTD or XML) schema referenced in document (ie 3 errors and 2 warnings). Are these also contributing to the HTTP 404 error?

Comment: correct URL for your servlet is "localhost:8010/TennisDatabasePooling/TennisdbaseServlet.do" 
and about the HTTP 500 error, change your import statement from:
import javax.activation.DataSource;
to:
import javax.sql.DataSource;

Comment: PJ, on this tage: <Context crossContext="true" docBase="SomeApp" path="" reloadable="true" >; is SomeApp my Project Name (i.e. TennisdbasePooling) or the filename (i.e. TennisdbaseServlet.java) of my application? Or simply "SomeApp" that should be there?

Answer (score 0):

When with the `j2ee` view  is provided as `JSP` why are u doing it with servlets only .Try to do it with JSP.Also i think your access pattern of the servlet is not correct this should be some thing like this `http://localhost:port/app-name/dbservlet`.Also u have not defined any servlet with `url-pattern` `/dbservlet`. Below is a good tutorial you can start with.
http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand how could the below code even compile:

```
Context envContext = null;
   try {

       Context envContext = new InitialContext();
```

First you should always get rid of the compile time errors and then try to call the servlet: below is the a compiler error free code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.sun.corba.se.pept.transport.Connection;


public class TennisdbaseServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public TennisdbaseServlet() {}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException, IOException {

   Context envContext = null;
   try {

       envContext =  new InitialContext(); 
       DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/postgres"); 
       Connection con = (Connection) ((Statement) ds).getConnection();

       Statement stmt = ((java.sql.Connection) con).createStatement();
       String query = "select * from tennis_teams";
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

       PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
       response.setContentType("text/html");
       out.print("<center><h1>Tennis Teams Info</h1></center>");
       out.print("<html><body><table border=\"1\" cellspacing=10 cellpadding=5>");
       out.print("<th>TEAM NUMBER</th>");
       out.print("<th>PLAYER NO</th>");
       out.print("<th>DIVISION</th>");

       while(rs.next())
       {
           out.print("<tr>");
           out.print("<td>" + rs.getInt("teamno") + "</td>");
           out.print("<td>" + rs.getString("playerno") + "</td>");
           out.print("<td>" + rs.getDouble("division") + "</td>");
           out.print("</tr>");
       }
       out.print("</table></body></html>");
   }  catch (SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (NamingException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
}
```

Try running it with this first and then debug the errors henceforth if any!!

Comment: Run the above code and url is: http://localhost:8010/TennisDatabasePooling/TennisdbaseServlet.do; but gives HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource cannot be cast to javax.activation.DataSource

type Exception report

message org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource cannot be cast to javax.activation.DataSource

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource cannot be cast to javax.activation.DataSource
...  Some help.